# Which file permissions are impacted by Git's core.sharedrepository setting?

Tags: git, file-permissions

There is a config setting in `git` that is named `core.sharedrepository` and which to my understanding impacts the way that git deals with file permissions.

My question is what files are meant?

Assuming my git repo is at `/home/user/project`

- the files in the `/home/user/project/.git` subfolder?
- the code files `/home/user/project/` but not .git?
- all files `/home/user/project` ?

the background to my question is that the files in `/home/user/project/.git` are created world readable `-rwxrwxr--`. I would like to have all files only accessible to either the specific user or at least a groupid member

Answer (score 1):

The setting affects both the files under `.git` (the repository itself) and the working copy. Having read or write permission to one but not the other would not be very useful, as most git operations require access to both.

If you have world-readable files in `.git`, check your `umask`. Does it allow this? You can test this by creating a file with `touch` and check its permissions.